# Refreshing a UITableView When Collection is Updated on Other View

Tags: ios

It is hard to describe my scenario but I will try. I have a UITableViewController which allows the user to see the details of an item. After the user visit the item details controller they open another controller and then add more items. I want to refresh my original UITableViewController once the items are added.

I can of course use the viewDidAppear event but I have noticed that it slows things. viewDidLoad is only fired once.

Any other ways to update the UITableView remotely!

Comment: Have you tried using an NSNotificationEvent to send out a signal when the table needs to be updated and then listen for it in your tableview class?

Comment: I have and it does not update since the UITableView is not visible on the screen at that time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use view will appear instead if view did appear.

Comment: I have explicitly indicated in the original question that I do not want to take this approach as it has performance issues.

Comment: You can implement protocol and your tableview will confirm to that protocol. As soon as you add another item call the method in that protocol that your tableview controller implements. Inside that method update your data source & call reload data method of table view .